# Can't dig out some information located under a linked-button

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape contact information from a ***[webpage](https://denver.craigslist.org/cto/d/2007-acura-mdx-awd/6900719788.html)***. There is a link connected to `show contact info` button which is supposed to take me to the contact ridden page. So, I parsed that link with the hope that I can reuse the link to reach the contact information. However, the newly produced ***[link](https://denver.craigslist.org/fb/den/cto/6900719788)*** leads me nowhere.

***How can I extract that information under `show contact info` button from that page?***

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://denver.craigslist.org/cto/d/2007-acura-mdx-awd/6900719788.html"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    item = urljoin(url,soup.select_one(".show-contact").get("href"))
    print(item)
```

When I try to click on that link manually or using selenium I end up getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: That webpage is using dynamic code to hide the contact details. They do so *for exactly the reason* that it makes it harder (for spammers) to scrape them.

Comment: I get 404 even by clicking on it.   Oh.....It has to be clicked and opened on same page!

Comment: Why they do it is known to everyone. However, my question is whther there is any way to unveil @Blckknght .

Comment: I think the answer lies in this script - https://www.craigslist.org/js/postings-concat.min.js?v=41bf2939565cec747e6f22d296638ee3  as to whether possible as it outlines what the page is doing for the tel number. If you grep/regex for captcha or tel you'll find the relevant bits.

Comment: Is selenium an option btw?

Comment: Any library will do as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `selenium` is the only way to achieve this, if all you need is clicking a `button` it's super easy to learn.

Basically you find the `element` through however you like, by `class`, `tags` or `ids`. Then you can interact with hit, in this case, you would want to use `element.click()`

Comment: Does it look like a clicking issue!!! If it was, I would never create this post. Thanks anyway @Aero Blue.

Comment: @MITHU You clearly don't understand, you need something like selenium because it's generated by javascript, you can't do it with requests. So yes, clicking is the issue....

Comment: Before creating this post I tried with selenium defining explicit wait, hardcoded delay and things but I never succeeded. Did you try that yourself to check whether what you are saying is right @Aero Blue? Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU Open your browser and click the info button, it works. It's `javascript` not magic... If you hardcoded selenium then why did you post this here, selenium is a step in the right direction at least.

Comment: @MITHU You need to build a website profile before instantly clicking contact info, make yourself not look like a bot.